# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: java, debian

Each time I try to apt-get update my Server i receive the following error (I tried to install Java):

```
root@ca002:~# apt-get update
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@ca002:~#
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Check out ask ubuntu in this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Comment: I already saw this but I forgot to read the bottom section, thanks man!

Comment: Do you have some tips / links again? https://hastebin.com/ejotayiwuw.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PPA software source you are trying to use does not exist.
If you look at the url,you can see that it tries to fetch the packages from the "Jessie" Ubuntu release.

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

Jessie is a Debian release, not Ubuntu.

Here is a [list](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/) of the currently available PPA repositories for Ubuntu releases.

Update your non-existent PPA software source link, to an existing one from that list and you should be able to install java. (If that was your goal)

Or just remove that PPA software source link if you are just trying to perform a general apt-get update.

You can find your list of PPA Software Sources under `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.
Alternatively you can use the update-manager for this.